# I'm trying to launch rplidar but I'm getting a timeout error

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, bashrc, ros, timeout

I've set up ROS noetic in my Raspberry Pi 4 B with Ubuntu 20.04. I want to make a map with my LiDAR, so I started by installing rplidar. However, when I run `roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch` (after doing `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`), my LiDAR starts spinning for a moment and then I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1700330979.765364372]: Error, operation time out. RESULT_OPERATION_TIMEOUT! 
[rplidarNode-1] process has died [pid 4674, exit code 255, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/8bff9a04-863c-11ee-8151-1d77f81a905d/rplidarNode-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/8bff9a04-863c-11ee-8151-1d77f81a905d/rplidarNode-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: could you share the log file?
/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/8bff9a04-863c-11ee-8151-1d77f81a905d/rplidarNode-1*.log

Comment: The weird thing is, that log file doesn't actually exist...

Comment: do you need to set the baud? is that the slamtec laser? if so, which version? $rosrun rplidar_ros rplidarNode _serial_baudrate:=256000  rosrun is used to run a single node, while roslaunch is used to launch multiple nodes from one or more packages

Comment: I have a YDLiDAR X2, I don’t think it’s slamtec. I tried the command and it just gives the same error, but shorter: [ERROR] [1700994344.997923947]: Error, operation time out. RESULT_OPERATION_TIMEOUT!

Comment: It’s from EAI (a brand, I think)