# I’m trying to launch rplidar but I’m getting a timeout error (reupload)

Tags: 20.04, bash, raspberrypi, ros, timeout

(I’m uploading this again because nobody answered the first time) I've set up ROS noetic in my Raspberry Pi 4 B with Ubuntu 20.04. I want to make a map with my LiDAR, so I started by installing rplidar. However, when I run roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch (after doing source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash), my LiDAR starts spinning for a moment and then I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1700330979.765364372]: Error, operation time out. RESULT_OPERATION_TIMEOUT! 
[rplidarNode-1] process has died [pid 4674, exit code 255, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/8bff9a04-863c-11ee-8151-1d77f81a905d/rplidarNode-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/8bff9a04-863c-11ee-8151-1d77f81a905d/rplidarNode-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

By the way, that supposed log file doesn’t exist.
I’m using an EAI YDLIDAR X2, with a baud rate of 115200 (which is also what the launch file says).
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to launch rplidar but I'm getting a timeout error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493144/im-trying-to-launch-rplidar-but-im-getting-a-timeout-error)

Comment: No, that was the last time I uploaded this question, but people only asked for more details and the only answer didn't work. Since then, no one has answered, and that's why I uploaded it again here.